# Using a FTSearch on a date field

Tags: javascript, full-text-search, xpages

In some SSJS I do a FTSearch to retrieve values that I then manipulate and feed to a repeat control. The query is pretty complex and I have it all working except this piece.

var qString = tmpArray[cTerms++] = "((FIELD [WFSCompletedDate] > " + dString + ") AND (FIELD WFSOrig CONTAINS \"" + user + "\"))";

and when the code runs it resolves to the below:

((FIELD [WFSCompletedDate] > 11/13/2013) AND (FIELD WFSOrig CONTAINS "Bill Fox/Workflo Systems"))

next I do:

```
var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = database.FTSearch(qString);
viewScope.put("vsCollCount",dc.getCount());
```

However, it never gets to the viewScope.put

In my overall query if I use all of it but comment out the line above the search works fine. The issue is that the code stops running at the FTSearch so dc.getCount is never executed. I have tried it with the [] and without them but the results are always the same. Where the field WFSCompletedDate is present in a document it contains a legitimate date, the field is never blank. Very confusing because in the larger query one part is:
query] = "(!((FIELD WFSStatus = Draft) OR (FIELD WFSStatus = In Process) OR (FIELD WFSStatus = Approved) OR (FIELD WFSStatus = Denied))AND (FIELD WFSOrig CONTAINS \"" + user + "\") AND [_RevisionDate] > " + dString + "  )"

and uses [_RevisionDate] and this does not cause a problem.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Check the sitesearch.ntf inside is all sorts of ftsearch magic and as far as I recall including date handling. Also just paste the string into notes and check what comes back

Comment: Does it work if you omit `tmpArray[cTerms++] =` in your code line?

Comment: Have you checked the xpages exception log in IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder?

Comment: I'm quite sure that this hasn't to do with your basic problem, but regarding FT syntax you EITHER use "FIELD fieldname ..." OR "[fieldname] ...". In other words: putting the field name into square brackets is an alternative to specifying a field

Comment: I second Lothar's assessment. `FIELD [WFSCompletedDate] > 11/13/2013` looks for an item with brackets in its name. `FIELD WFSCompletedDate > 11/13/2013` or `[WFSCompletedDate] > 11/13/2013` look for an item without brackets in its name. But Knut is on to something too: that double assignment syntax looks wrong... in the context of your larger code that we're not seeing, it might be "right", but if you want to make troubleshooting easier, steer clear of any code patterns that *look* wrong even when they're right.

Comment: WFSCompletedDate is a date/time field so I need to do a date/time comparison if I use FIELD WFSCompletedDate > 11/13/2013 in the search bar I get the error "Relational operators not supported in text fields" same result if I just use [WFSCompletedDate], so the issue is how to get a date comparison. I use [_RevisionDate] > somedate in another places in the same query. I will look through the sitesearch.ntf to see if that gives any ideas.

Comment: the syntax would appear to be "WFSCompletedDate is after 11/15/2013" the script goes through to completion but does not select anything. It would appear for working with the query in a Notes view that when I select the field WFSCompletedDate it does not see it as a Date/Time field (even though the document properties says it is) so I can not build a query "is after". I tried it with a different date field in the document and the query builder sees it as a date and I can select is after. So it would now be an issue of how to get the FTIndex to see the field as a date. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on all the comments and re-comments this is my assumption:

The Notes client's advanced FTSearch dialog analyzes the item's datatype based on its design time definition, and not based on some values stored in it: we all know that we can put mostly anything into an item using backend classes, no matter what datatype the field was given at design time. An error usually won't occur befor the data are being combined with the form element.

So, to me it looks as if at design time the field's datatype had been set to Text while at runtime it somehow is reveiving date time values, most probably through (LotusScript?) backend codes.

Try to get your database and design elements into a form where you can perform a client based FT search fitting your needs. If that is working it most probably will also work as a code driven FT search.

Btw: if you build a query using "FIELD [WFSCompletedDate]" you're in fact looking for a field whos name contains the brackets, and as there's no such field on your forms you don't run into any errors, but of course you won't get any hits either.

EDIT: just found this one here: [Query is not understandable - using field Fulltext search [Tags] = "foo"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518730/query-is-not-understandable-using-field-fulltext-search-tags-foo?rq=1) : be sure to read Thomas Adrian's own answer regarding multiple fields of the same name in his database!

Comment: One addition: if there is only ONE document in your database where the WFSCompletedDate field contains a text value, then each fulltext query using a relational operator like < and > will fail. If in doubt, remove the fulltext index, write an agent that checks the field type of this field in every document. If the field type is correctly set to datetime in every document you can create the ft index again.

Comment: Because this was in a development DB I deleted all the documents, removed all the documents that might contain the field, removed the FTIndex, made a new copy, then added the field to the Notes Form with type date/time. Created some new documents and the search worked. In my example above I used the [WSFCompletedDate] as one of many iterations to try to get the query to work and clearly it is wrong, it should have been [WFSCompletedDate > 11/15/2013] which makes it a date comparison. Thanks all for your input.